# VBA Excel cannot use Controls library

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code like this below. but as per the print, .Controls option is no showing and i'm receiving Compile error: Method or data member not found

any idea on how this is happening and how to fix it ?
many hours looking for a solution without success. thanks

```
Private Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
PLN_ESTOQUE.Controls("combobox" + i).Value = "test"
End Sub
```

[image]

[image: My Project References]

Comment: What kind of object is `PLN_ESTOQUE`? Is it a `User Form` control?

Comment: Looking to what Intellisense shows, it looks to be a `Worksheet` object. If so, this object does not have any controls property... If I am right, what kind of control is the `ComboBox` in discussion? A sheet Form type or an Activex ComboBox?

Comment: Hi PLN_ESTOQUE is a worksheet and Combobox is and ActiveX object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not answer my clarification questions, supposing that the object in discussion is a `Worksheet', test the next way, please:

```
Sub testComboObject()
 Dim cb As DropDown, cb1 As MSForms.ComboBox, sh As Worksheet, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 i = 1
'In case of a ActiveX ComboBox:
 Set cb1 = sh.OLEObjects("ComboBox" & i).Object
 cb1.Clear
 cb1.AddItem "Test1"
 cb1.ListIndex = 0
 
 'In case of a sheet Form ComboBox (DropDown):
 Set cb = sh.Shapes("Combo" & i).OLEFormat.Object
  cb.RemoveAllItems
  cb.AddItem "Test1"
  cb.ListIndex = 1
End Sub
```

A combo box does not receive a value like a Text Box. You should add items and then set the combo `ListIndex` property to make it having a value...

Comment: worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.
As per my understanding the .controls will just work if i use in in a userform but not in the worksheet, right ?

Comment: Hello, its me again (Like Adele) I have an array that I have created previously called ArrProd if I use the command me.combobox1.list=ArrProd it works nice. but if i use cbl.List=Arrprod I receive the error 424 message. what am I doing wrong now ?

Comment: @Lucas: If I remember well, Error 424 means "Object required". So, I think that you forgot to properly define the `cbl` object. Without seeing the context of your code I cannot say more about the issue... If your code refers a User form or a Worksheet, `Me` means the parent object of the combo (the Form or the Sheet). If you use only a variable not previously defined, VBA does not know what kind of object it is and if it has a `List` property or not...

Answer (score 0):

i've create the following function to mount an array with a list of products

```
Public Function MontArrProdutos()
Dim shtBD_PROD As Worksheet


Set shtBD_PROD = Sheets("BD_PROD")
lastrow = FindLastRow(shtBD_PROD, "B")
arrProd = shtBD_PROD.Range("A2:B" & lastrow).Value



End Function
```

After that I made a Little small modification to your code

```
Sub testComboObject()

 Dim cb As DropDown, cb1 As MSForms.ComboBox, sh As Worksheet, i As Long
 MontArrProdutos ' CALL THE FUNCTION TO MOUNT THE ARRAY OF PRODUCTS
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 i = 1
'In case of a ActiveX ComboBox:
 Set cb1 = sh.OLEObjects("ComboBox" & i).Object
 'cb1.Clear commented this in order to make minor changes to code
 'cb1.AddItem "Test1" commented this in order to make minor changes to code
 'cb1.ListIndex = 0 commented this in order to make minor changes to code
cbl.List= arrProd ' inserted this line only to populate the combobox1

end sub
```

all of this is inside a worksheet, i'm not using any form in project